# can Minimal API handle big request?

Tags: flutter, asp.net-web-api2, minimal-apis

I want integrate Flutter with an ASP.NET API. the problem is when I create minimal API, the JSON I retrieved from MapGet taken too long to load, is the limit for how big can minimal api load?

this is my scheme

```
[
  {
    "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "drPi00001": "string",
    "drPi00002": "string",
    "drPi00003": "2023-06-13T07:18:32.792Z",
    "drPi00004": "string",
    "drPi00005": "2023-06-13T07:18:32.792Z",
    "drPi00006": "2023-06-13T07:18:32.792Z",
    "drPi00008": "string",
    "drPi00011": "string",
    "drPi00012": "string",
    "drPi00013": "string",
    "drPi00014": "string",
    "drPi00015": "string",
    "drPi00017": "string",
    "drPi00018": 0,
    "drPi00019": "string",
    "drPi000Ud": "2023-06-13T07:18:32.793Z",
    "drPi000Ub": "string",
    "drPi00022": "string",
    "drPi000Ds": "string",
    "drPi00023": "string",
    "drPi000Id": 0,
    "drPi00007": 0,
    "drPi00009": 0,
    "drPi00020": 0,
    "drPi00021": 0,
    "drPi00016": 0,
    "drPi00010": 0
  }
]
```

and this my MapGet code,its same as example i look into :

```
app.MapGet("/todoitems", async (TestingDbContext db) =>
    await db.DrPi000s.ToListAsync());
```

and this is my builder

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TestingDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer("WebApiDatabase"));
builder.Services.AddCors(option =>
{
    option.AddPolicy("allowedOrigin",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
        );
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

is there any way to solve, otherwise, how to get only specific attribute in the model?